# Get/findById returns null in Bootstrap

Tags: session, grails, bootstrapping, findby

when i try to get an object in the bootstrap via User.get(1) or User.findById(1) I get always null returned. I saved the object before with new User(...).save(flush: true) and the user is already in User.list()...

who knows the reason/mistake?

thx

Comment: Are you sure that the id is 1 for the saved user object? Try printing the ids of the users returned by `User.list()`.

Comment: I'm having precisely the same problem. Record in the database, perform a .get() on the correct index, and I get a null ref exception. However, it appears that grails reexecutes the code after the exception, and retrieves the correct record, and everything works fine. Using grails 1.3.7

Answer (score 1):

The domain is probably not being saved due validation errors.

replace your

```
user.save(flush:true)
```

for

```
if (user.validate()) {
  user.save(flush:true)
} else {
  user.errors.allErrors.each { println it }
}
```

It will print all validation errors in your console.

Comment: If the user is appearing in `User.list()` then it is probably saving ok, but I agree with Lucas that save()'s should always be checked in Grails. Some people prefer to throw a validation exception if something in Bootstrap doesn't save, and it has the advantage of being shorter to type: `user.save(failOnError:true)`